# How to enter data in textbox and click on button in someones website programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to scrap data from website, i can do this using Import.io but i have to learn that how can i do by write simple program in C#.

Assume that page contain One textbox and one button , and when click on button its give search result .

```
Page1 : www.example.com
Search : <input type="text" value="abc" id="search" >
<input type="submit" id="submit">

Page2: www.example.com/result.aspx
<body>
<p>you have entered abc</p>
</body>
```

Now i want only data of result.aspx when i run my localhost:5585/deafult.aspx.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its seems you are fresher here

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data which has been input in page 1 to page 2 somehow. The simplest way would be to use a query string parameter.

Update your Page 1 mark up to use server controls:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_OnClick" />
```

Create a click event for the submit button:

```
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var redirectUrl = string.Format("/result.aspx?input={0}", search.Text);

    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

Then in Page 2, on page load you want to grab this from the query string:

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var input = Request.QueryString["input"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        litResult.Text = input;
    }
}
```

You'll need to update your Page 2 mark up slightly also:

```
<body>
<p>you have entered <asp:Literal ID="litResult" runat="server" /></p>
</body>
```